# Ruby - Savon - Connecting to web service - 'new' : wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, web-services, wsdl, savon

I'm using Savon to connect to a web service via WSDL I'm getting the error shown below for all attempts to connect using this library.  The frustrating thing is that I had code that I've been using to test for several weeks and it hasn't had an issue until today.  I'm completely baffled by this.  I wrote a new script using nothing but Savon to connect to the service and I get the same error.

**I'm getting this error:**
*test_ConnectToWSDL.rb:4:in `new': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentE
rror)
        from test_ConnectToWSDL.rb:4:in`'*

I've checked and double check this code and according to the Savon docs this should be completely valid.

**My code**

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new "http://myservices.com/service.svc?WSDL"

client.lookup_by_sku do |soap|
  soap.body = {
    :includeStuff => includeStuff,
    :includeStuff2 => includeStuff2,
    :searchStuff => [
        {:"V1" => V1,
          "V2" => V2,
          "V3" => V3,
          "V4" => V4,
          "V5" => V5,
          }
        ]
    }.to_xml
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what happened.  I installed Savon::Spec and it updated my Savon gem to the 0.8 beta3 version which for some reason doesn't like the argument passed for 'new'.  If I found out a fix for this or why this code doesn't like the beta gem I'll post again to save someone else 4 hours of their companies money.  :)